# Enabling GPU Rendering From Fedora CLI

Tags: rendering

I am building two rendering nodes using Fedora. Each includes an NVIDIA 4090 GPU. I have installed the drivers, and dependencies, and both show up using nvidia-smi and nvtop. However, when I render a scene, that successfully uses GPUs on Win 10, it is using CPUs only.

I am using using Blender 4.0.1.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Michael